# Формулы для физического движка для 2D игрушки

Tags: delphi, разработка-игр

Подскажите формулы, которые пригодились бы для физического движка "физически продуманного тетриса" и "прыжков в платформере".

Comment: Вот только не нужно говорить возьми учебник... и т.п.

Comment: а готовый не подойдет? http://code.google.com/p/box2d-delphi/

Comment: Нет, готовый не подойдет.

Comment: +ко всему, мануала, как я понимаю на русском к нему не найти, так как я его впервые вижу именно для делфи.

Comment: Ну он же опенсорсный. Вы всегда можете посмотреть его исходники и сделать так же.

Comment: А что такое "физически продуманный тетрис" ?  

Что там есть, масса фигуры + сила поворачивающая ее, сопротивление среды, фигуры падают с ускорением ? Где в тетрисе применить физику ?

Comment: А законы физики вас чем не устраивают?

Answer (score 4):

F = ma

v(t) = v0 + at

ЗЫ, Извините, но вопрос такой . )

---

Ок для пыржков в платформере вам подойдет траектория тела брошенного под углом горизонту.

```
  x = x0 + v0 * t * cosα 
  y = y0 + v0 * t * sinα - (g * t^2) / 2
```

Хотя в платформерах чаще этим не заморачиваются и проекции скорости по осям константны. Просто вводят некоторый потолок по `y`, после которого меняется знак.

Comment: Чет, по-моему, мало инфы... К примеру, что за сила? Что за "а" в формуле Сила=Масса х "а".

Comment: Ускорение, разумеется. Это второй закон Ньютона.

Answer (score 0):

[@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate), жжоденько.

А по делу, пожалуйте учить [матрицы преобразований](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Матрица_перехода):) Естественно это азы, пишется легко, работает быстро, на дельфях с правильным подходом даже на канвасе простейшие примитивы в 3д + тени отрабатывает на ура.

Comment: Матрицы это хорошо, но это уже для отрисовки. А "физически продуманный тетрис" надо сначала рассчитать координаты и ориентацию объектов. А для этого знать второй закон крайне полезно. Ну и надо  еще столкновения объектов рассчитывать.

Comment: Вы правы. Просто тут ответов на вопрос уйма. Надо бы сузить круг как-нибудь.